# Code coverage in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, code-coverage, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco, eclemma

I have added testCoverageEnabled=true in my build.gradle file in order to start getting some code coverage reports.

Running my tests I can see that a code-coverage folder is added in my build outputs folders. However, when a reach its contents I see there is only a coverage.ec file...

What can I do with this file in order to get a recent report? Or what should I add to my build.gradle in order to get the full report?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get code coverage using Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683022/how-to-get-code-coverage-using-android-studio)

Comment: Did you ever get it working? I'm currently trying to set up unit testing on android studio...

Answer (score 2):

(EDIT: My old answer used Jacoco to get code coverage. With Android Studio's latest updates, you can get code coverage without third party tools)

With the new Android Studio, you are able to run your unit tests and see the coverage all within the IDE.

First, you'll need to get your unit tests running in the IDE. (if you already can, then skip this step)

This [guide](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/) and [demo](https://github.com/mutexkid/android-studio-robolectric-example) will help you.

Secondly, you'll need to create a JUnit Run configuration

[image]

Inside this configuraiton, you'll be able to choose

- **Test Kind:** "All in Package"
- **Package:**  [the package where your tests reside, eg: "com.myapp.tests"]
- **Search for tests:** Across Module Dependencies (could be diff for your
  setup)
- **VM -options:** -ea
- **Working Directory:** [your project's directory]
- **Use classpath of mod:** [select your module]

If you have any issue creating your JUnit Run Configuration, you should visit [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/how-to-run-robolectric-junit-tests-in-android-studio/) guide for help.

Lastly, in the latest Android Studio, you should be able to run your JUnit-Run Configuration by clicking on the 'Run with Coverage' button.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to the "build.gradle" file

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"
```

Run the test using

```
gradlew :<module>:createDebugCoverageReport
```

Run the command from the project root replacing "module" with the name of the module under test.

The output should be in the module under "build/outputs/reports/coverage"

Comment: Does not seem to work: Task 'createDebugCoverageReport' not found in project ':...'.

Comment: Was already able to run it, but once again I only get a coverage.ec file