# How to get Coverage Report of Unit Test in Android Studio using command line?

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line, code-coverage, test-coverage

In referring to the answer in [How to get code coverage using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683022/how-to-get-code-coverage-using-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top), we could generate Junit Test coverage on Android Studio. I could even dump out the Coverage Report in HTML format using menu Analyze->GenerateCoverageReport...

I'm thinking of getting this run from command line to get the test run with Coverage, and automatically dump out the Coverage Report in a designated folder. Is there a command that I could do so? (I'm in a linux/mac environment)

Comment: Note that I could use `./gradlew test` to run the test on command line. But this doesn't seems to run it with coverage nor dump out any coverage report.

Comment: use Jacoco, it works